# Integration of Django Rest Framework with SSO and generating JWT token

Tags: django-rest-framework, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, django-rest-framework-jwt

Can any 1 suggest any way to integrate SSO using SAML with Django Rest Framework and generating JWT token. Python version 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

This medium blog should help:
https://dev.to/lewiskori/building-web-apis-with-django-lb4

Comment: This doesn't contain in SAML integration.